# Send file from angular to create new and download from .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, angular, typescript

I've been trying to download .xml file, but sadly unsuccesfully.
From angular side I am  sending `*.xml` file. In .NET side I take it to process and create a new `*.xml` file. And I need to download that new file, however I can't really find out how to workaround it.

this is my `file-component.ts`:

```
OnSubmit(value, File) {
  const params1: FormData = new FormData();
  params1.append('File', this.fileToUpload, this.fileToUpload.name);
  params1.append('ProcessingMode', value.processingMode);
  params1.append('StartDate', value.startDate.formatted);

  const params = {
      'File': this.fileToUpload,
      'ProcessingMode': value.processingMode,
      'StartDate': value.startDate.formatted
  };

        this.mapsConfigurationService.postFile(value, this.fileToUpload, value.startDate.formatted)
        .subscribe((res: any) => {
                  this.downloadFile(res, 'xml'); debugger;
                  this.xmlProcessing = false;
              },
                  (err) => {
                      if (err.status === 401) {
                          //  this.router.navigate(['unauthorized']);
                      } else {
                          this.xmlProcessing = false;
                      }
                  });




downloadFile(data, type) {
  const fileName = 'test';
  var contentType;
  if (type === 'xml') {
      contentType = 'text/xml';
  }
  var blob = new Blob([data._body], { type: contentType });
  const dwldLink = document.createElement('a');
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const isSafariBrowser = navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') !== -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') === -1;
  if (isSafariBrowser) {
      dwldLink.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
  }
  const fullFileName = fileName + '.' + type;
  dwldLink.setAttribute('href', url);
  dwldLink.setAttribute('download', fullFileName);
  dwldLink.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  document.body.appendChild(dwldLink);
  dwldLink.click();
  document.body.removeChild(dwldLink);}
```

this is `service.ts`

```
postFile(value: any, fileToUpload: File, startDate) {
const formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('File', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);
formData.append('ProcessingMode', value.processingMode);
formData.append('StartDate', '2015-05-23');
return this.http
  .post(this.Url, formData);
```

}

and this is backend side:

```
[HttpPost, DisableRequestSizeLimit]
    public ActionResult UploadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            var xml = Request.Form.Files["File"].ToString();
            var httpRequest = HttpContext.Request.Form;
            var postedFile = httpRequest.Files["File"];
            string outputFile = Request.Form["info"].ToString();
            var startDate = Request.Form["StartDate"];
            var file = httpRequest.Files[0];
            string fullPath = "";
            string folderName = "Upload";

            string antFile = @"C:\ant.bat";
            string build = @"C:\build.xml";


            string rootPath = @"C:\Users";
            string newPath = Path.Combine(rootPath, folderName);
            if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);
            }
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                string fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
                fullPath = Path.Combine(newPath, fileName);
                using (var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                }
            }

            return PhysicalFile(@"C:\Book1.xml", "application/xml", "Book1.xml");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            return StatusCode(500);
        }
    }
```

I get error 500 and I do understand that the problem is with RequestHeaders but I can't  figure out the way to solve it and in which side

Comment: You may want to add some logging to that catch block, and then check what exception is being caught

Comment: It executes `return PhysicalFile(@"C:\Book1.xml", "application/xml", "Book1.xml");` and exits it doesn't catch any exceptions but in developer tools I recieve 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: You have a catch block just underneath that, doing `catch (System.Exception ex)`, and then `return StatusCode(500);` below. The exception is being caught here I imagine, which is why you receive a 500 error.

Comment: But as I debug code it doesn't go into that catch block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for downloading for downloading any file... I am use this code in backend
and make and request the code from angular by normal http request

```
            var myFile :: your file

    if (System.IO.File.Exists (myFile.Path)) {// to know if the file is Exist or not
     //Process File Here ...
    } else {
      return Json ("NotFound");
    }
    string contentType = "application/xml"; 
    HttpContext.Response.ContentType = contentType;

    var result = new FileContentResult (System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes (myFile.Path), contentType) {

      FileDownloadName = $"{myFile.Title }" // + myFile.Extension

    };

   // System.IO.File.Delete (myFile.Path);  //if you want to delete the file after download

    return result;
```